# How to implement JavaScriptCore debugger?

Tags: javascript, xcode, javascriptcore

JavaScriptCore contains debugger package which is written in c++. 
This is the [link](https://github.com/phoboslab/JavaScriptCore-iOS/tree/master/JavaScriptCore/debugger) of debugger package.

Can we use this debugger for debugging java script from eclipse or xocde, 
Any reference or sample implementation will be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: I think you already know about this debug tool but just for your consideration. Modern web browsers have in-built debug tool. [Chrome V8 debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), [Firefox Firebug](https://github.com/firebug/firebug) and so on. They are open-source project. So if you are interesting about developing a debugger for IDE, you can check the each of project code.

Answer (score 6):

The WebKit folks have recently moved the JavaScriptCore-specific portion of the WebKit Web Inspector (aka Safari's Web Inspector) into JavaScriptCore itself with the intent to allow remote debugging JSContext objects in iOS apps the same way you can debug UIWebView objects now. This feature is supposed to ship with iOS 8.

JavaScript debugging in the Web Inspector is actually built on top of JSC::Debugger so you can either adapt it or use it as a reference implementation. The code lives [here](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/JavaScriptCore/inspector/), but it seems that it won't work as-is without iOS 8 or OS X 10.10. Still, it seems like a good starting place if you want to build your own debugger interface.